# Creating Hexagonal Cartogram JSON file in d3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, cartogram

I am trying to make a hexagonal cartogram in d3.js, similar to the one found [here](http://www.ralphstraumann.ch/projects/information-imbalance-africa-on-wikipedia/). Mike Bostock mentions this in his (awesome) Eyeo 2013 talk, and has created a tool to allow a user to point-and-click draw a hexagonal polygon ([here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5249328)).

What I'm wondering is how to use the tool to create a static cartogram in json/geojson and classify the various polygons (countries in both the examples above) into a useable format to bring into a d3 project.

In other words, once computation has been done to determine the desired scale of hexagon and how many hexagons are needed for each enumeration unit (again, countries in the examples), how would one go about creating the json file for the cartogram?